# Returning More Than 1 Byte to a Function in Assembly

Tags: assembly, avr

I'm new to assembly (I'm using an Arduino Uno with AVR assembly) and I can't figure out how to return variables of more than 1 byte from an assembly function. So far, I have only needed to return bytes, and I have simply modified the r24 register with `mov` and `ldi` to the value I wanted to return. When I call `ret`, the function returns the value in register r24 to a program in C. But how do I return values larger than 8 bytes? Basically, how do I use memory instead of the registers.

Comment: read the ABI. Or if you don't use any external functions you can just invent your own ABI and do anything you want and return any how you like

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Thank you for that. I found the abi here: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/avr-gcc  Though I would still like to know how to use the system memory to return data instead of registers, since I am going to need to return an array. I modified my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the page you have linked in your comment ([gcc.gnu.org/wiki/avr-gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/avr-gcc)) read the chapter "Calling Convention". Unfortunately it's a bit more complicated than for other CPUs.

If the value returned is **longer than 8 bytes** the C compiler will allocate the memory and pass the address of the memory in registers R25:R24.

All arguments are shifted "down" by two registers. Example:

```
byte someFunction1(byte a, byte b);

a -> R24
b -> R22
return -> R24

struct largeStructure someFunction2(byte a, byte b);

a -> R22 (instead of R24)
b -> R20 (instead of R22)
address of tmp_mem -> R25:R24
return -> in memory tmp_mem
```

If the value returned is **up to 8 bytes** long the value is returned in the following registers:

```
1 byte: R24
2 bytes: R24...R25
3 bytes: R22...R24
4 bytes: R22...R25
5 bytes: R20...R24
6 bytes: R20...R25
7 bytes: R18...R24
8 bytes: R18...R25
```